# Using std::move in Constructor with value error handling

Tags: c++

Im confuesd about the usage of `std::move` in class constructors.

I want to pass a value to a class and check in the constructor if a valid value is passed. If not an exception is thrown.

Before i used to pass the value by const reference:

```
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const std::string& value)
        :m_value{ value }
    {
        if (value == "Foo") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};
```

Now i read in modern c++ it is better to pass by value and move the passed value into the class variable:

```
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::string value)
        :m_value{ std::move (value) }
    {
        // Now m_value must be used because value is empty if reference
        //if(value == "Foo")  -> Desaster value is moved away = empty
        if (m_value == "Foo") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};
```

So far so good i can just refer to the class variable to do my error checking. Now i started to modernize a codebass which has a class hierachy were an value is already defined in the base class. The child class basically performs additional checks on the variable and throws.

Here a simplified example:

```
#include <string>

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(std::string value)
        :m_value{std::move(value))}
    {
        // value is "empty" here because its moved into m_value
        if (m_value == "Foo") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }

    std::string get_value() const { return m_value; }
    void set_value(const std::string& value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};


// Version 1
// We have to ask several times the base class to get the compare value
class Foo : public Bar {
public:
    Foo(std::string value)
        :Bar{ std::move(value) }
    {
        if (get_value() == "BAR" || 
            get_value() == "Bar" || // perform several checks here
            get_value() == "bar") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }
};


// Version 2
// We need to make a copy to check. Doesn't this ruin the purpose of 
// std::move by saving a copy??
class Foo : public Bar {
public:
    Foo(std::string value)
        :Bar{ std::move(value) }
    {
        auto check_value = get_value();

        if (check_value == "BAR" ||
            check_value == "Bar" || // perform several checks here
            check_value == "bar") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }
};


// Version 3
// doesn't work except we provide in the base class a default constructor
class Foo : public Bar {
public:
    Foo(std::string value)
        //Error here we need to provide a default constructor
    {
        if (value == "BAR" ||
            value == "Bar" || // perform several checks here
            value == "bar") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }

        set_value(std::move(value));
    }
};
```

So my question is, which approach is the best. Or how can this be handled better?

Comment: I don't see any moving going on in your second example… also, you should prefer `std::string_view`-parameters over `std::string const&`. `std::string` or `std::string&&` is only superior when you have an expiring value anyway.

Comment: if you use `std::string_view` do you still use `std::move` ?

Comment: You use `std::string&&` and move, as well as `std::string_view` and copy.

Comment: i fixed the second example i pasted the wrong code. sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the error-checking first:

```
Bar(std::string value)
: m_value{m_value == "Foo" ? throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid") : std::move(value)}
{}
```

Respectively, if the error-checking is more complicated, consider putting it in its own function:

```
void check_args(std::string const& s) {
    if (get_value() == "BAR" // perform several checks here
    || get_value() == "Bar"
    || get_value() == "bar")
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
}

Foo(std::string value)
: Bar{ (check_args(value), std::move(value)) }
{
}
```

Also consider two constructors, accepting respectively a `std::string&&` (if you already have a temporary) or a `std::string_view` (if you don't).
Delegating to a common implementation internally is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are encountering is that `Bar::get_value()` eagerly copies. The advice is that *parameters* should be values, but *results* might still sensibly be `const &`.

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(std::string value)
        :m_value{std::move(value))}
    {
        // value is "empty" here because its moved into m_value
        if (m_value == "Foo") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }

    const std::string & get_value() const { return m_value; }
    void set_value(std::string value)
    {
        m_value = std::move(value);
    }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};

// We have to ask several times the base class to get the reference, and the compiler is able notice we don't change it in between
class Foo : public Bar {
public:
    Foo(std::string value)
        :Bar{ std::move(value) }
    {
        // value is "empty" here because its moved into Bar
        if (get_value() == "BAR" || 
            get_value() == "Bar" || // perform several checks here
            get_value() == "bar") {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I thought in general getters should return by value not by const reference.

Comment: @Sandro4912 It *doesn't matter* for types that can only be copied, but for types that benefit from moving, no, you don't

Comment: @Sandro4912 and I would just have `public: std::string value;` in this case